# wp_signon not working fine and 302 moved temporarily?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, login

I am using **wp_signon** function.

This is my ajax code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/ajax/loggedin.php',
                cache : false,
                async : false,  
                data : {
                    'uname' : login_id,
                    'upass' : login_pass
                },
                success : function(html){

                jQuery("#LoadingImage").hide();
                    if(html.trim() == 'ok'){    alert("sd");
                        jQuery('#login_error').html("You will be redirected soon...");
                        window.location="http://www.iguanapaint.com/";
                        //window.location(site_url+"/dashboard/");
                    }else{
                        jQuery('#login_error').html('<div class="error">Invalid Username or Password</div><p class="mrgn"></p><div class="clear"></div>');
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            });
```

and this is PHP code...

```
include_once('../../../../wp-config.php');
if($_POST['uname']!="" && $_POST['upass']!=""){ 
    $uname = sanitize_user($_POST["uname"]);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST["upass"]);   
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $uname;
    $creds['user_password'] = $upass;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );  

        if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
             $login_error = $user->get_error_message();                    
            echo    $login_error;
         }else{         
            echo "ok";          
         }

}
```

When I am signing in then it is not redirecting me to iguanapaint.com instead shows error **invalid username and password** while now if reload the page then it sets the cookie and it is already **loggedin**.

And also when I see in firebug it shows two ajax request.

1 - to loggedin.php and shows that **302 moved temporarily**
2 - to iguanapaint.com

Comment: Instead of `alert("sd");`, have you tried `alert(html.trim());` to see what is actually being returned?

Comment: @s_ha_dum In return total html is coming of home page (iguanapaint.com)